# form1.show() does not work after adding WebBrowser to windows form

Tags: c#, node.js, visual-studio, winforms

I have a weird project I'm working on that is a summation of AngularJS, NodeJS, C# written as a Microsoft solution (.sln) project package. The issue I'm having is that I would like to make a windows form that has the WebBrowser .NET component within it. When I press the button that prompts the form to open, nothing happens. However, when I delete the WebBrowser component from the form, it opens just fine. I've seen from past posts that this could be a threading issue, but if you look at my code snippets below, you can see that I've tried it and still have the issue:

[app-bar.component.html: (where the button is called)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TmEm.png)

[app-bar.component.ts: (method that correlates to the html button)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21rKd.png)

[form1.cs: (since the button is on form1, this is where I create the form3 and have the show method)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2ole.png)

[form3.cs: (windows WebBrowser form)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Lar0.png)

[form3.Designer.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzJQp.png)

Please let me know if you guys have any advice, would be much appreciated!

Comment: Update: CefForm.show_record();

Comment: Please post code. Not images of code ...

Comment: @a_polo，what do you mean about  CefForm.show_record();? As others suggested, It is best for you to show the related code about your question.